# CentOS - how to use ln command in this situation?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, symbolic-link

Create a file like the log file in CentOS, when this log file is updated, then the copy of the log file is also updated. Maybe I use this command:

```
ln -s logfile copy_of_logfile
```

Then when logfile's content is added, a copy_of_logfile's content is also added ==> it's OK, but when logfile's content is deleted, the copy_of_logfile's content is also deleted.

I want it to be when logfile's content is added, a then copy_of_logfile's content is also added, and when logfile's content is deleted, I want the copy_of_logfile's content to NOT be deleted. Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ln -s logfile copy_of_logfile
   then logfile's content is added, copy_of_logfile's content is also added
```

Uhm, no. If you create a softlink then you still only have **one single file**.
Any action on that single file will how up on both directory entries.

Let me clarify that with two examples:

Example 1: It is as if you created two entries in a mobile phone address book with the same phone number. You get the same result when calling.

Example 2: Using a book (the index is the directory entry)

Before linking:

```
Index 
---------------------------------
About the author           Page 1
Index                      Page 2
Hansel and Gretchen        Page 3-10
Sneeuwwitje                Page 11-14
Intentionally left blank   Page 15
About the author.          Page 16
---------------------------------
```

And after **soft** linking:

```
Index 
---------------------------------
About the author           Page 1
Index                      Page 2
Hansel and Gretchen        Page 3-10
Sneeuwwitje                Page 11-14
My copy of Sneeuwwite      See index entry for Sneeuwwite
Intentionally left blank   Page 15
About the author.          Page 16
---------------------------------
```

In the example to story still end up at the same pages. If you edit one of the stories then both will get changed.

If you use a **hard** link rather than a soft link:

```
Index 
---------------------------------
About the author           Page 1
Index                      Page 2
Hansel and Gretchen        Page 3-10
Sneeuwwitje                Page 11-14
My copy of Sneeuwwite      Page 11-14
Intentionally left blank   Page 15
About the author.          Page 16
---------------------------------
```

> it's ok, but logfile's content is deleted, copy_of_logfile's content is also deleted

Yes, because it is the same file. It is not a copy.

Since you want to be able to delete from one of the files without deleting from the other file (the copy), you will need **two** distinct files.

Either log to two files, or split the output using [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee).

An alternative is to use [`tail -f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) to read all new information added to the original log file. (and add that to your backup).

---

Comment: That rather buries the lead a bit.  Your answer could do with an explicit "Make a hard link instead." sentence somewhere, preferably near the start.  (-:  And, strictly speaking, when there's a hard link there's one file, with two links.  When there's a symbolic link, there's actually two files, one a regular file and one the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

would be an idea to use the syslogd deamon?
In its config file /etc/syslog.conf you can specify the log file(s) for your applicaton/severity, etc.
For more: http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rh-cm-en-1.0/s1-software-syslog.html

Comment: +1 because it is probably the correct way to solve TrungTrung's problem (though not the asked question).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to obtain what you wish: a running copy of a given file. It can be obtained by creating a *named pipe*,

```
   mkfifo mypipe.logfile
```

which, as its name suggests, is the file to which you will write the log, then reading from it with the `tee` command, to send the output to two identical files:

```
   cat mypipe.logfile | tee -a logfile 1>> copy_of_logfile
```

This will automatically generate two identical files, which are kept in step as new material is added to each of them.

If you want to make sure the process never stops, add a `while` loop,

```
   while [ true ]; do cat mypipe.logfile | tee -a logfile 1>> copy_log_file; done
```

This may scripted, started at boot, respawned if you want it to run forever, and so on.